# WebGL trying to draw multiple points

Tags: webgl, draw, bezier, curve

I'm trying to draw curve lines using Bezier, I try to do all in `void main()` and try to do with buffer, but it's wrong everywhere, and I don't understand where:

1) All in `main()`

```
var VSHADER_SOURCE =
  'attribute vec2 a_Position;\n' +
  'void main() {\n' +
  '  gl_Position = a_Position;\n' +
  '  gl_PointSize = 10.0;\n' +
  '}\n';
var FSHADER_SOURCE =
  'void main() {\n' +
  '  gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n' +
    '}\n';
  function main() {  
   var canvas = document.getElementById('webgl');  
   var gl = getWebGLContext(canvas);
        if (!gl) 
    { 
        console.log('Failed to retrieve the <canvas> element');
        return; 
    } 
        if (!initShaders(gl, VSHADER_SOURCE, FSHADER_SOURCE)) 
      {
        console.log('Failed to intialize shaders.');
        return;
      }
    gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
    w=(192*4);
    d=(w/1920);
    x=0.8;
    y=0.9
  var M = new Float32Array([-x,-y,-x+d,y,-x+2*d,-y,-x+3*d,y,-x+4*d,-y,]);
  var vertices=[]; 
for (var i=0;i<6;i+=2)
    {
        for (var t=0 ;t<1;t+=0.01)
        {
        vertices.push((1-t)^2*M(i)+2*(1-t)*t*M(i+2)+t^2*M(i+4));
        vertices.push((1-t)^2*M(i+1)+2*(1-t)*t*M(i+3)+t^2*M(i+5));
        }
    }
       var a_Position = gl.getAttribLocation(gl.program, 'a_Position');
        if (a_Position < 0) 
       {
       console.log('Failed to get the storage location of a_Position');
       return -1;
       }
         for(var l = 0; l < lenght(nx)/2-1; l+=1) 
         {                
          gl.vertexAttrib2f(a_Position, vertices[l], vertices[l+1]); 
          gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);
         }
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(a_Position);
}
```

And second method I can't write because space is limited.

Comment: Why don't you begin to implement drawing with buffer using static data, like some vertices. Once this work fine, implements your bezier algorithm to create curves...  http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?page_id=1217

Answer (score 1):

Did you even attempt to debug this yourself? Like [open the JavaScript console and look for errors](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/)?

The code you posted isn't remotely runnable.

First off your shader

```
attribute vec2 a_Position;
void main() {
  gl_Position = a_Position;
  gl_PointSize = 10.0;
}
```

won't compile and your framework (or whatever you call `initShaders`) should have printed an error that `gl_Position (a vec4) can not be assigned by a_Position, a vec2`. Change `a_Position` to a vec4.

Next up is these lines

```
   vertices.push((1-t)^2*M(i)+2*(1-t)*t*M(i+2)+t^2*M(i+4));
   vertices.push((1-t)^2*M(i+1)+2*(1-t)*t*M(i+3)+t^2*M(i+5));
```

`M` is not a function. I'm guessing you meant to use `M[expression]` not `M(expression)`

```
   vertices.push((1-t)^2*M[i]+2*(1-t)*t*M[i+2]+t^2*M[i+4]);
   vertices.push((1-t)^2*M[i+1]+2*(1-t)*t*M[i+3]+t^2*M[i+5]);
```

`^` is not the raise to a power operator in JavaScript [it's the bitwise xor operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Bitwise_XOR_assignment). To raise a number to a power you use [`Math.pow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow). So you probably wanted this

```
  vertices.push(Math.pow(1-t,2)*M[i]+2*(1-t)*t*M[i+2]+Math.pow(t,2)*M[i+4]);
  vertices.push(Math.pow(1-t,2)*M[i+1]+2*(1-t)*t*M[i+3]+Math.pow(t,2)*M[i+5]);
```

Then this line

```
    for(var l = 0; l < lenght(nx)/2-1; l+=1)
```

There is no function `lenght` nor is there a function `length` in JavaScript nor did you declare a variable called `nx`

It seems like you wanted

```
    for(var l = 0; l < vertices.length; l += 2)
```

You probably also want to use [multiline template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for your shaders and your `initShader` function is very poorly written based on the fact that looking at your code you're accessnig `gl.program` which is not a thing.

At the end of the code you posted you have this line

```
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(a_Position);
```

But that line only makes sense if you're using a buffer for your data. You're not. You're instead drawing one point at a time. You should use a buffer as it would be much much faster than calling `gl.drawArrays` once for each point

Might I suggest some [other WebGL tutorials](https://webglfundamentals.org)?

Here's a working? version.

```js
var VSHADER_SOURCE = `
  attribute vec4 a_Position;
  void main() {
    gl_Position = a_Position;
    gl_PointSize = 10.0;
  }
`;
var FSHADER_SOURCE = `
  void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  }
`;

function main() {  
  var canvas = document.getElementById('webgl');  
  var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
  if (!gl) 
  { 
    console.log('Failed to retrieve the <canvas> element');
    return; 
  } 
  if (!initShaders(gl, VSHADER_SOURCE, FSHADER_SOURCE)) 
  {
    console.log('Failed to intialize shaders.');
    return;
  }
  gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  var w=(192*4);
  var d=(w/1920);
  var x=0.8;
  var y=0.9;
  var M = new Float32Array([-x,-y,-x+d,y,-x+2*d,-y,-x+3*d,y,-x+4*d,-y,]);
  var vertices=[]; 
  for (var i=0;i<6;i+=2)
  {
    for (var t=0;t<1;t+=0.01)
    {
      vertices.push(Math.pow(1-t,2)*M[i]+2*(1-t)*t*M[i+2]+Math.pow(t,2)*M[i+4]);
      vertices.push(Math.pow(1-t,2)*M[i+1]+2*(1-t)*t*M[i+3]+Math.pow(t,2)*M[i+5]);
    }
  }
  var a_Position = gl.getAttribLocation(gl.program, 'a_Position');
  if (a_Position < 0) 
  {
    console.log('Failed to get the storage location of a_Position');
    return -1;
  }
  for(var l = 0; l < vertices.length; l+=2) 
  {       
     gl.vertexAttrib2f(a_Position, vertices[l], vertices[l+1]); 
     gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);
  }
}

// THIS IS A POORLY WRITTEN FUNCTION!!!!
// Normal WebGL pages use multiple shader programs
// therefore you should **NEVER** assign values to 
// the gl object!!!
function initShaders(gl, vsrc, fsrc) {
  gl.program = twgl.createProgram(gl, [vsrc, fsrc]);
  gl.useProgram(gl.program);
  return !!gl.program;
}

main();
```

```css
canvas { width: 384px; height: 216px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/3.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="webgl" width="1920" height="1080"></canvas>
```

Comment: You're the best!Best of the best!